# How to draw a sloping grid?

Tags: tikz-pgf, graphics

Could you help me make the code to draw a sloped gride like the image below in Ti*k*Z?

[image]

Comment: Here is a similar problem where the solution also applies if you want your grid to be not rotated, but skewed. http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/198352/tikz-how-to-apply-an-affine-transformation

Answer (score 12, accepted):

This draws a single grid, rotated by 45 degrees, with open lines at the outer boundary, with blue lines, the step is `0.5` units, by constructing a `grid` path.

If the grid boundary should be drawn, make sure the grid interval boundaries are integer multiples of the `step` size, say `(2.5,2.5) grid (2.5,2.5)`, for example (not shown here, although)

The second example is just for fun: Drawing a bunch of rotated grids.

```
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage{tikz}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}
\draw[step=0.5,blue,rotate=45] (-2.4,-2.4) grid (2.4,2.4);
\end{tikzpicture}

\begin{tikzpicture}
\foreach \x in {10,20,30,45,50,60,70,80} {
\draw[step=0.5,blue,rotate=\x] (-2.4,-2.4) grid (2.4,2.4);
}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: @NetinhoSantos: You're welcome. Please add some starter code in future. Happy TeXinG!

Comment: Why writing `scale=1`? I think that's the default.

Comment: @Alenanno: Ooops, that's the remainder of old code. I'll remove it. Thanks!