# Separately xscaling and yscaling shapes AND line widths in TiKZ

Tags: tikz-pgf, pgfplots, tikz-styles

I know how to scale a shape in TiKZ. The following code snippet draws two rectangles, where the first rectangle has a line width of 2 and the second rectangle is a scaled version of the first one, with xscale=6 and yscale=2.

```
\documentclass{report}
\usepackage{tikz,pgfplots}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\draw[line width =2] (0,3) rectangle ++ (1,1);                        % First rectangle (original)
\draw[line width =2,xscale=6,yscale=2] (0,0) rectangle ++ (1,1);      % Second rectangle (scaled version)
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
% Labels
\node at(10,3.5) {First rectangle (original)};
\node at(10,1) {Second rectangle (scaled version)};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Here is a preview:
[image]

What I want to do, is to scale the line widths, as well as the shapes. In particular, I wish the scaled version of the first rectangle to look like the following
[image]

The difference is that the xscaling and yscaling actions have impacted everything, and the vertical and horizontal lines have a thickness of 6 and 2, respectively. None of the methods I found (like [this](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/515300/can-i-scale-all-line-widths-in-a-tikzpicture) or [using affine transformation with scope](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/198352/tikz-how-to-apply-an-affine-transformation)) seem to work. I appreciate your time.

**Addendum**

I need a general answer. That said, I may have many shapes in a tikzpicture, each of which being scaled, rotated or generally transformed differently. Therefore, an answer to this question **must** only affect the **intended** shape, not any other ones. Furthermore, the shapes are general (i.e. they can be rectangles, ellipses, stars, polygons, etc.)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Instead of scaling the shape itself, you could transform the canvas on which the shape is drawn, like drawing on an empty balloon and then blowing it up:

```
\documentclass{report}
\usepackage{tikz}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\draw[line width =2] (0,3) rectangle ++ (1,1); 
\begin{scope}[transform canvas={xscale=6,yscale=2}]
   \draw[line width =2] (0,0) rectangle ++ (1,1);     
\end{scope}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Nicely done (+1).